# Extracting data to a new model

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table like the following:

[image]

I want to extract data like below. Please how can I do that?

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: Also, please don't post text as an image, post it as `text`; it is *text* after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and `group by`:

```
select max(case when hierarchy = 'A' then l_name end) as A,
       max(case when hierarchy = 'B' then l_name end) as B,
       max(case when hierarchy = 'C' then l_name end) as C
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by hierarchy order by l_name) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```